# Why more than one "using system" namespace?

Tags: c#

[image]

I don't get why, when I start a new console solution in C#, it has more than one "using system" lines. Shouldn't Using System cover using system.text and the rest?

Comment: "Shouldn't Using System cover using system.text and the rest?" - Nope. That's not how it works.

Comment: `using` is not recursive, it only applies to the immediate namespace and not to sub-namespaces.

Comment: Just imagine how many type collisions you would have if `using System` was recursive!

Comment: Here's a link to the documentation where it says [_A using directive does not give you access to any namespaces that are nested in the namespace you specify._](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sf0df423.aspx#Anchor_1)

Comment: Now how do I mark juharr as answering this for me...

Comment: Plus the compiler would have to search _all_ system namespaces for type resolution rather then just the specified ones.

Answer (score 3):

If `using System;` were recursive, then, in just the "mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" assembly, this would be list of type collisions you would get:

> __Filters, __HResults, <>c, <>c__DisplayClass11_0, <>c__DisplayClass4_0, AsyncCausalityStatus, AsyncReplySink, BIND_OPTS, BINDPTR, CALLCONV, CausalityRelation, CausalitySynchronousWork, CausalityTraceLevel, ChannelInfo, ConfiguredTaskAwaiter, CONNECTDATA, ContractHelper, DebugView, Decoder, DESCKIND, DESCUNION, DictionaryEnumerator, Disposition, DISPPARAMS, ELEMDESC, Encoder, Entry, Enumerator, Environment, EventData, EXCEPINFO, ExplicitlySet, FILETIME, FUNCDESC, FUNCFLAGS, FUNCKIND, Getter, IDLDESC, IDLFLAG, IEnumerable, IEnumerator, IExpando, IMPLTYPEFLAGS, InternalPartitionEnumerable, InternalPartitionEnumerator, INVOKEKIND, IReflect, KeyCollection, Keywords, LIBFLAGS, MdSigCallingConvention, NameInfo, Node, NodeEnumerator, OpFlags, PARAMDESC, PARAMFLAG, ParseFailureKind, Reader, RemoteAppEntry, Segment, SerializationMask, SinkStack, State, STATSTG, SYSKIND, Tasks, TokenType, TYPEATTR, TYPEDESC, TypeEntry, TYPEFLAGS, TypeInfo, TypeKind, TYPEKIND, TYPELIBATTR, UnsafeNativeMethods, ValueCollection, VARDESC, VARFLAGS, Variant, Win32

And in the current project I have open, with 14 assemblies loaded I would have 792 type collisions (of the 14,251 types defined).

That's why it's not recursive.

Here's how to run this yourself:

```
var typeCollisions = String.Join(", ",
    System
        .AppDomain
        .CurrentDomain
        .GetAssemblies()
        .SelectMany(a => a.GetTypes())
        .GroupBy(x => x.Name)
        .Where(x => x.Skip(1).Any())
        .Select(x => x.Key)
        .OrderBy(x => x));
```